Properties of Image of the Pre-Image of the Image of a Subset of the Domain & Pre-Image of the Image of the Pre-Image of a Subset of the Codomain
I know the title somehow sounds like a tongue twister but, mathematically it is much easier to explain. The definition of image and inverse image of a subset is as provided in the textbook on section 3.5(page 71) and section 3.6(page 74) respectively.
On page 79, theorem 3.6.26 states that a function $f : X → Y is$ one-one if and only if $A=f^{-1}(f(A))$ for each $A \subseteq X$.
Also, theorem 3.6.27 states that a function $f : X → Y$ is onto if and only if $f(f^{−1}(B)) = B$ for each $B \subseteq Y$.
Our professor had however two interesting propositions.
For any function $f : X \rightarrow Y$,
(1) $\forall A \subseteq X, f(f^{-1}(f(A)))=f(A)$
(2) $\forall B \subseteq Y, f^{1}(f(f^{-1}(B)))=f^{-1}(B)$
Proof of (1):
Let $y \in f(f^{-1}(f(A)))$. Therefore, $\exists x \in f^{-1}(f(A))$ such that $y=f(x)$.
Now $x \in f^{-1}(f(A)) \implies f(x) \in f(A) \implies y \in f(A)$ . Thus, $f(f^{-1}(f(A))) \subseteq f(A)$.
Convesely, let $y \in f(A)$. Therefore, $\exists a \in A$ such that $y=f(a)$. Now, since $f(a) \in f(A)$ by the definition of $f^{-1}(f(a))$, we have $a \in f^{-1}(f(A))$. Thus $f(a)\in f(f^{-1}(f(A)))$ i.e. $y \in f(f^{-1}(f(A)))$. Therefore $f(A) \subseteq f(f^{-1}(f(A)))$.
Thus, we can conclude that $f(f^{-1}(f(A)))=f(A)$
I couldn't prove (2) and need help for how I should approach. I also intend to verify my proofs of the statements by someone else.
